# Can I use "wrong" "right" in this way?

Tags: word-choice

> I think your data is wrong.
>   Your answer is right.

Are the usages of “wrong” incorrect? My teacher says to me that I should always use “right” and ‘wrong” when using on people, but when it is about something objective, I should only use “correct” and “incorrect”.

Comment: It depends on context; "wrong" and "right" are synonyms for "incorrect" and "correct" respectively.

Comment: It could be (as some answers say) that the teacher is *simplistic* or *pedantic*.  Or it could be that the student has an incomplete understanding of what the teacher said.

Answer (score 2):

Your teacher's view is simplistic.

"That tie is the **wrong** colour for your shirt." The subject is a tie not a person.

"That tie is the **incorrect** colour for your shirt." The English is OK but but the use of **incorrect** is strange.

and a bit further ...

"John has done it the **wrong** way." The subject is a person.

**wrong** as an adjective

"John has answered **incorrectly**." The subject is a person.

**incorrectly** as an adverb (adjectives for verbs)

Following the logic of your teacher's rule we should say "John has answered **wrongly**." which is incorrect (or wrong).

As with many rules that deal with a varying percentage of English constructions, your teacher's rule does not always apply.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are saying that your teacher wants you to judge people's action as *right* or *wrong*, but to judge the fits of objects as *correct* and *incorrect* (tell me if I'm wrong). If so, I think your teacher is being *pedantic* and happens to be wrong.

What your teacher is asking you to do is to take a side in a debate about the relationship between moral terms and natural terms, i.e. are ethical terms merely social or do they reflect something more real?